# How do i install Ubuntu MATE on an Ubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: 20.04, mate, ubuntu-mate

I have a PC with limited resources so I want to install a lighter Linux version like Ubuntu MATE. I tried:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-mate
```

but that does not work. Could not find package.

Comment: Ubuntu Manta is not a supported variant of Ubuntu here, as it's not an official variant.

Comment: @ThomasWard Did I get it all wrong :) ... Is there really an Ubuntu Manta?

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) ... Although I recommend a fresh install of Ubuntu MATE, the desktop environment itself is available for regular install as a meta-package like so:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

Then, the Ubuntu MATE desktop can be chosen from the login screen.

Comment: Which will lighten the runtime "load", but require extra storage space.

Comment: @Hannu It will lighten the load and keep installed applications, settings  and data. ... *Storage space is the sacrifice to offer* ... It's either this or a fresh install.

Comment: Yep, but note that "resources" may well be HDD/SSD space.

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression you're not that experienced;

The easiest way to swap distribution (whatever way) is:

1. Backup your data,
2. Install a fresh copy of the selected OS,
3. Reinstall applications
4. Restore data from backup.

Note that SETTINGS files for applications is best recreated;
it might be a cause for random problems if you have an incompatible setting brought over from e.g. an older version of an app.