# Dummy output not fixed in 22.04 or 20.04. Ubuntu LTS. How about go back to 18.04.6 Bionic Beaver for my 12 year old PC?

Tags: 20.04, sound

About six months ago my 12 year old Ubuntu Linux installation running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a 17 year old Gateway stopped playing music.

I seemed to remember, the sound card stopped working a day after I ran one of those software update pop-up messages.

The sound stopped working a day after I ran one of those software update pop-up messages.

I expected the next software update would fix the sound.

The built in sound stayed broke for several months. I searched AskUbuntu and Google for how to fix the sound problem. Problem continued.

I was running Ubuntu 20.04 and I decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I installed 22.04 LTS and the machine is a Whoa Nelly Mess. My old PC is unusable with 22.04 LTS. What do I do now?

I went and looked at the Ubuntu dot com front page. There one can see that Canonical is creating Ubuntu Core 22 for IOT or Internet of Things. That is the way software development goes - the developers have to catch the wave of opportunity.

For my situation, I am planning to reinstall an older Ubuntu. I am going to find an old install flash drive.

I just tried booting the 12 year old system from a USB flash drive with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Sound works from the flash drive Ubuntu.

The important news is Booting from a flash drive allows me to confirm. The PC sound hardware is OK.

I will install an older Ubuntu. I plan to carefully not over write my 12 years of emails and data.

A great system, just gotta budget for frustration sometimes.

Comment: I suggest you try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1301214) for audio … and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404578) for a lighter desktop environment so you can keep your current instructions

Comment: instructions —-> installation … spelling autocorrection on my phone :-)

Comment: Use what works for you.

Comment: I did the installation of 18.04.6 Bionic Beaver from a USB stick. The sound system works on Bionic Beaver. Unfortunately, all of my data and emails and keyboard aliases is on the previous 22.04 LTS. I did not mention in my original post, the gnome left side program icon strip is playing itself with triple images, and the firefox snap program is broken. I thank Raffa and mikewhatever for suggestions.

Comment: I did install Ubuntu 18.04.06 which did fix the primary no sound "Dummy Output" problem.Unfortunately all my emails, data, aliases and files are still with the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The install software made a new partition for the 'new' Ubuntu 18. The story so far is: Reinstalling an older Ubuntu is more complicated that it looked like at first.

Answer (score 0):

lmckusic@dapit:~$ cat howtorollbackfrom20to18
How to Roll back from 20.04 Ubuntu to Ubuntu 18.04 by Lee McKusick
July 14, 2022

I finally decided to roll back from Ubuntu 20.04 "Focal Fossa" released on April 23, 2020. I rolled back to Ubuntu 18.04 "Bionic Beaver"released on April 26, 2018.

The reason for rolling back is simple: The Ubuntu 20.04 sound software shows a "Dummy device" message at the sound control panel. I need to get the sound on my 15 year old PC working.

Sound now works. Mplayer now plays analog stereo at the 3.5mm audio jack. Good.

The bad news is Evolution email is broken. I can see 5 or 6 hours of fiddling to fix Evolution.

I have not done device, partition and file management by hand for 15 years. These are notes on how to identify the devices, identify the file systems and use the Installer to plug he file systems into the Ubuntu framework.

Roll back here means, moving your entire home directory, say from Ubuntu 20 back to a Ubuntu 18 operating system. First we get two filesystems ready, then we plug them into the Ubuntu 18 Installer program. Bingo, you save your years of data and return to an older Ubuntukernel and software.

Overview of the steps.

Step 1. Find your old Ubuntu Install flash drive or Ubuntu Install CD. I used a Ubuntu 18.04 'Bionic Beaver' flash drive from 2018.

Step 1.1 Make a backup of your entire /home/username/*file system. I use rsync with a 2 terabyte USB drive.

Step 2. Get a sheet of paper. You have to write down the device names and the name of the filesystems inside the devices. Be aware that devices like /dev/sda5 are also called partitions.

Step 3. Walk through the device table. We are mainly interested in the devices that follow the "Extended" device.

```
We use the mount command with -f fake and -v verbose options.
mkdir mountpoint
```

sudo mount -fv /dev/sda9 mountpoint     # -f fake
repeat without -f
sudo mount -v /dev/sda9 mountpoint      # syntax ok, do it nonfake

## Look at mountpoint with ls

sudo umount -v /dev/sda9           # clean up or get confused.

```
Note the device that contains the '/home/username' files.

Note the device that contains the '/' Linux file tree.

Make note of any other interesting partitions.
```

Step 4. Boot the Ubuntu 18 installer USB device or CD. Allow several minutes.

Step 5. In the Installer open a terminal and run 'sudo gparted'. Gparted run from the bottom of page menu is not root. Gparted with out sudo can't alter partitions.

```
Enlarge the device with '/' root (/dev/hda9 for me) and enlarge the /home user partition.
```

Step 6. Exit gparted and run it again and confirm that the enlarge action worked.

Step 7. Verify the root and user file system with e2fsck /dev/hda9. sudo may be required.

Step 8. Enlarge the root and user file system with resize2fs /dev/hda9  sudo may be required.

Step 9. Double check that both devices and their enclosed ext4 file systems have been enlarged as said above.

Step 10. Get a name, username, computer name, password, and timezone ready.

Step 11. Start the "Install Ubuntu" script.
Choose "Installation Type Something Else"
What is the /dev/sd? id of your root partition?
Click on that row.
Click on the prompt "Type" and answer Ext4
Click on mount type. Answer '/'
What is the /dev/sd? of your /home/username partition?
Answer Type prompt.
Click on mount type. Answer '/home'

Comment: The UbuntuInstaller is tricky but clever. The installer is attaching file systems to a mount location.

Step 12. Short notes on making some applications work as expected after rollback.
Need to enhance the Vi editor with
apt-get install vim-doc vim-gtk3 vim-common vim
To make vi use correct encryption method, do :setlocal cm=blowfish2
If the backup data contains . files like .bashrc you will get back your aliases.

```
Best wishes, cordially yours, Lee McKusick.
```

Be on the alert for the InstallUbuntu software package (part of the flash drive installer) possibly changing the size of a file system. If your normal start up fails with messages about "Starting user 121..." it may be caused by one of your file systems being too small.

Another reason for writing things down is the device and filesystem programs have slight inconsistencies in syntax. Get the commands right and then write it down.

Step 2. Get a bootable Ubuntu install device. I used an 8 gig flashdrive from my last Ubuntu 18 install activity.
Step 3. Start your present Ubuntu and list out your disk partition table

## Run fdisk -l as root - much better display

sudo fdisk -l

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    976895    974848   476M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2          978942 976771071 975792130 465.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5          978944 415359132 414380189 197.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       419459072 485044223  65585152  31.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       939665408 976771071  37105664  17.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8       415361024 419457023   4096000     2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda9       569919488 939663359 369743872 176.3G 83 Linux

The devices after the Extended partition /dev/sda2 like sda5 have a label Linux
The task now is to find the partition with your user files and your system files.

One of these devices (sda5 to sda9) has your user files and it mounts to home/
Another one of these devices has the rest of the Ubuntu operating system and it mounts to /

Step 4: We are going to mount each device to a mountpoint. Then see what filesystem and files are inside the device. Carefully unmount the devices after each test.

Boot your flash drive and open a terminal.
Make a mount point. We change to flash drive user home.
cd
mkdir mountpoint    #mountpoint is plain directory.
ls                  #See mountpoint listed

## Use -f fake -v verbose to double check.

mount -vf /dev/sda9 mountpoint      # -f fake mount repeat as required

mount -v /dev/sda9 mountpoint       # Should actually work if spelling is right.

ls mountpoint               # Look for what has been mounted

If you have found the '/' root filesystem you will see this.

bin    dev   initrd.img      lib64       mnt   root  snap      sys  var
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lost+found  opt   run   srv       tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lib             media       proc  sbin  swapfile  usr

If you see a bunch of your own files, this partition contains the /home user filesystem

Write this on paper: Mark up the device list like /dev/sda5 and the file system identified.

Unmount file system
umount -v /dev/sda9

Here is a glimpse of what we are headed for:
lmckusic@wayback:/$ mount | grep sda

/dev/sda9 on /     type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro) #space to emphasize alignment
/dev/sda5 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=32745)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=4)      #never touched by us

Step 5 Enlarge the / and /home device and filesystems.

Now, start up the Ubuntu Install flash drive or CD.

It appears to me that the Ubuntu System Install script does something that changes the size of the devices (like /dev/sda5) when it builds the structure around the  / and /home file systems.

On the install flash drive start a Terminal, see bottom left programs.
From the terminal, start gparted as root.

sudo gparted /dev/sda # Without sudo, gparted can not change partition sizes.